# Passing Api Post Request for multiple Objects in Flutter

Tags: flutter, object, post

This is my post api code which will work on postman but how can i post this from flutter end? i am new. i tried different things but it does not work

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy the original text to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should create PostModel,User and Rider models . Every class should have the method to convert data to json format

```
class PostModel
{
   User user;
   Rider rider;

   Map<String,dynamic> toJson()=>_$ConvertPostModelToJson(this);
}

class Rider
{
  String v_name;
  String v_number;
  String v_color;
  String v_email;

  Map<String,dynamic> toJson()=>_$ConvertRiderToJson(this);
}

class User
{
   String u_email;
   String u_password;
   String u_role;
   String u_name;
   String u_contact;
 
   Map<String,dynamic> toJson()=>_$ConvertUserToJson(this);
}
```

You should import http and dart:convert libraries into your code to convert
models to json object and send them to server .

[You can find more information about http library](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

[You can find more information about json serialization](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json)

[You can find more information about sending model to server using post](https://androidkt.com/http-post-request-in-flutter/)

Comment: Can you please make a function for posting this specific data post in Flutter

Comment: I have create these model but did'n know to make a function for it

Answer (score 1):

Please use Dio package.

```
dio: ^4.0.6
```

```
 Map<String, dynamic> body = {
    'apiToken': apiToken,
    'langCode': 'en',
  };

Response response = await dio.post('YOURAPI',
        options: d.Options(headers: body));
```

Here, I am use Dio package for api calling.

Answer (score 1):

```
    final response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(
        {
          'User': {'u_email': '...', ...}, 
          'Rider': {'v_mail': '...', ...}
        }
      )
    );
```

See [Send data to the internet](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/send-data) for more information.